# Possible reason for crash?

Tags: mapkit, ios7

I am using a mapview and sporadically get crashes in iOS7 (both simulator + device). It looks like this:

> Exception Type:
>
> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS) Exception Codes:
>
> KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000000000000c
>
> Application Specific Information: objc_msgSend() selector name: points
>
> iPhone Simulator 463.9.4, iPhone OS 7.0 (iPhone Retina
>   (3.5-inch)/11A465)
>
> ```
> Thread 23 Crashed: 0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x03ea10b2 objc_msgSend + 14
> ```
>
> 1   MapKit 0x02bd9f0d -[MKPolylineView drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:] + 54
>
> 2   MapKit 0x02bd98ff __43-[MKOverlayView overlay:drawKey:inContext:]_block_invoke + 847
>
> 3   MapKit 0x02bd9572 -[MKOverlayView overlay:drawKey:inContext:] + 268
>
> 4 VectorKit 0x0c54741d -[VKRasterOverlay drawKey:inContext:] + 61
>
> 5   VectorKit 0x0c5455e5 __40-[VKRasterOverlayTileSource _queueDraw:]_block_invoke + 485
>
> 6   libdispatch.dylib 0x04ccd818 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
>
> 7   libdispatch.dylib 0x04ce24b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
>
> 8   libdispatch.dylib 0x04cd0ef1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 287
>
> 9   libdispatch.dylib 0x04cd113d _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
>
> 10  libsystem_c.dylib 0x04ffae72 _pthread_wqthread + 441
>
> 11  libsystem_c.dylib 0x04fe2d2a start_wqthread + 30

As you can see none of my "own" code is executed. Do you have any guesses on how to proceed finding the root of this problem?

Comment: I think you have the same problem like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957257/mkmapview-dealloced-when-calling-addoverlay) and there is also a [radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/17089661) filed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error's stack, I look at [MKPolylineView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolylineView_class/Reference/Reference.html) . It says that this class is deprecated in iOS 7, use `MKPolylineRenderer` instead...

Not your code ? 
Ok, I go up a little in the stack, same thing for [MKOverlayView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009715) :

> In iOS 7 and later, use the MKOverlayRenderer class to display
>   overlays instead.

It seems MapKit went into some changes !

Comment: But the call is deprecated and not removed, so it really should be possible to still have an app working that use those calls. Or am I wrong about that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this on the main thread? If not, try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  // here goes your UI-operation on your mapview
});
```