# MKMapView dealloc'ed when calling addOverlay

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm having an issue with my mapView being dealloced when I call this in `- (void)viewDidLoad`

```
NSString *template = @"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
self.onlineOverlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template];
self.onlineOverlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;
[_mapView addOverlay:self.onlineOverlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
```

The log is:(with zombie objects enabled)

```
*** -[VKRasterOverlayTileSource invalidateRect:level:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xf1863e0
```

It only happens when I dismiss the view controller containing the map view too soon.
If I wait a few seconds it doesn't crash.
The view controller gets dismissed by pop'ing it from the navigation controller,

I've tried several options:

1. `mapView` & `mapView.delegate` is set to `nil` in `- (void) dealloc and in - (void)viewDidDisappear`
2. `BOOL finishedLoading` that is set to `FALSE` when the view loads and set to `TRUE` when the map view delegate method `- (void)mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView fullyRendered:(BOOL)fullyRendered` is called.
3. `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddOverlayRenderers:(NSArray *)renderers` seems to be called before the method is done.

How can I check if the overlay has been fully added?

Or is it possible to cancel the overlay if the view controller gets dismissed?

**EDIT:**
The view controller is in a navigation controller stack and is presented and popped.
I'm not using any threads myself. From instruments I can see that there is another thread, so my guess is that `addOverlay:` is creating a thread somewhere.

The mapView is a property of the viewController and is the delegate as well.

Comment: There should be no such thing as "fully added". The fact that there is a delay between the time you add the overlay and the time when it becomes safe to dismiss the containing view controller suggests a threading issue. Please show / describe the _whole_ code / context in which you are adding the overylay.

Comment: I've added some more information. I hope it is enough, thanks.

Comment: You must have an implementation of `mapView:rendererForOverlay:`. Use logging to see if this is being called _after_ the view controller was dismissed. If so, maybe you should return nil if the map no longer exists.

Comment: I've set `_mapView = nil` just before I pop the view controller. Then in `mapView:rendererForOverlay:` i check for nil, but that doesn't help, it still crashes.

Comment: I was afraid of that. - If you do a google search on "VKRasterOverlayTileSource crash" you will find you are not alone. However, I find no definite solution. The problem is apparently that downloading of tiles continues after you leave the view controller and everything is deallocated. But I do not know how to prevent that, because the downloading is being automatically done for you. :(

Comment: Ah bugger. Do you have any suggestions for how to deal with it? Any way i can present and dismiss my view controller without crash? If you write the above comment in an answer i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: What I've said isn't an answer. I'd like to hear an answer myself! In two days this question will be eligible for a bounty and I am strongly thinking of adding one.

Comment: BTW: This is already [reported to apple](http://openradar.appspot.com/17089661) So create a bug report with reference to this report to increase the probability to get this fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Set a pointer to your mapView in the tileOverlay subclass.  This way the mapView is still alive when the result block is called.  You will have to manually add the mapView property in your tileOverlay subclass.

`NSString *template = @"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
self.onlineOverlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template];
self.onlineOverlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;
self.onlineOverlay.mapView = _mapView;
[_mapView addOverlay:self.onlineOverlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];`

Comment: MKTileOverlay doesn't have a mapView property.

Comment: Yes, but you can add a strong MKMapView property to your overlay subclass, like I said above.  You don't need to use the class but the strong pointer will keep the instance alive for the result block callback.  Add this line to your overlay subclass @property (nonatomic, strong) MKMapView *mapView;

Comment: Ah sorry, for some reason I didn't catch _subclass_. I get it now, will try it out.

Comment: @anton Gregerson if this worked for you please mark this as a correct answer for others to reference.

Comment: This leaks memory because it creates a retain cycle.

Comment: It seems not to crash when just removing the overlay from the mapView (e.g. in viewDidDisappear). IMHO this is better, because referencing the map view can create a retain cycle.